# Is there a way to display primary tabs vertical in separate block?

Tags: 7, blocks

In Drupal 7 I want to rearrange standart drupal tabs (eg. 'View' and 'Edit') as vertical and move it to sidebar. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: To make them display vertical, you will need to alter your theme's CSS. `.your-tab-class { display: block !important; float: none !important; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Tabs` rendered in **page.tpl.php** like this:

```
<?php if ($tabs): ?>
        <div class="tabs">
          <?php print render($tabs); ?>
        </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

in the main content div:
You can override the **page.tpl.php** in your custom theme and move this part of code to sidebar:

something like :

```
<div class="sidebar">
<?php if ($tabs): ?>
            <div class="tabs">
              <?php print render($tabs); ?>
            </div>
    <?php endif; ?> 
</div>
```